# Question regarding streams in java

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, inputstream, outputstream

We have the below requirement.

We will have to create an excel/pdf report and then download it on click of a button in a java web application.  The pdf/excel file is dynamically created using application data.

We **should not** create any physical file on the server.

How do we go about this? Are there any streams through which I can read and write in the same go without having to close in between.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to read and write the same stream ? (or maybe I misunderstood your question...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use memory-based streams (such as `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`) and use the same underlying byte buffer to address the read/write in the same go part of the question.

As others have pointed out, you can just write directly to the output stream of the response.

Comment: I every web framework I'm aware of you have access to a `OutputStream` to write your response to, so why would I want to cache the result in a byte array first?

Comment: I was trying to answer the "are the any streams through which I can read and write in the same go without having to close in between".  You are completely write though, you could just write directly to the output stream of the web framework.

Comment: There are 2 different objects above(input and output streams).What I want is something like both the functionality in one stream. Is it possible?

Comment: @vinoth: Nope, I am afraid. BTW, even if it is, how do you think you will be able to achieve desired result?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point in the OPs question. Then you are right, using `ByteArray*` with a shared backing array is the straightforward way in doing this. (although I doubt this is terribly useful for generating PDFs or whatever)

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`ServletResponse.getOutputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29).

You need to write to this stream from the one created by your report API. Don't forget to set the proper `content-type` using `setContentType()` method of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find how you can do it with jxl API and it may help you also.
[How do I output an Excel file from a Servlet?](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/faq/)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever PDF or Excel API you are using to generate the files, you should lookup the constructor or method which takes an `OutputStream` to write the generated PDF/Excel content to. You should just feed it with `response.getOutputStream()` **instead of** `FileOutputStream`.

For example, iText for PDFs:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
// ...
```

And Apache POI for Excel:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
WritableWorkbook workBook = Workbook.createWorkbook(response.getOutputStream());
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a Servlet serve the pdf/excel file as a byte array.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    
    byte[] bytes = null; // get this from somewhere in your app
    String fileName = "filename.pdf"; // whatever you wish to name the file

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    out.write(bytes);
    out.flush();
}
```

MIME type for MS Excel files would be `application/vnd.ms-excel`.